# Reducing loops in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I would like to implement the following snippet using just the inntermost for loop(the one which iterates 3 times),as this consumes a lot of time.

```
for i in arange(r):
    for j in arange(c):    
        for k in arange(3):
            if m[i,j]==n[i,j,k]:
                 new[i,j]=old[i,j,k]
```

Could anyone suggest a better method?

Answer (score 5):

```
for k in range(3):
    ind = m == n[:,:,k]
    new[ind] = old[:,:,k][ind]
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at using `itertools.product` - never used it with numpy arrays, but it might just work (and don't see why not)

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(arange(r), arange(c), arange(3)):
    if m[i,j]==n[i,j,k]:
         new[i,j]=old[i,j,k]
```

Comment: The main reason why not would be that this does most of the work in Python. A pure-numpy solution is preferable, at least when one is considering performance. And a pure-numpy solution isn't too hard.

Comment: @senderle fair enough - I must admit to addressing the question of reducing the "for loop" too literally. I can see that proper usage of numpy arrays is a much better option.

Comment: To be fair, this is the right solution in many cases :) -- just probably not when the objects in question are `numpy` objects.

Answer (score -1):

Since `arange(c)` is computed for each `i`, and `arange(3)` for each couple `(i, j)`, computing them once and for all outside the loop could save some time:

```
range_j = arange(c)
range_3 = arange(3)
for i in arange(r):
    for j in range_j:    
        for k in range_3:
            if m[i,j]==n[i,j,k]:
                 new[i,j]=old[i,j,k]
```

Of course this is only valid because these ranges are independent from `i` and `j`.